# Web based download manager

Tags: downloads, remote

At some places some ports/protocols are disabled such as ssh. So it's simply not possible for me to use such things like `wget`.

So I am looking for a download manager that I can control it over HTTP protocol. When I mean download manager, I mean an http and ftp downloader not a torrent client.

Are there any software packages like that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at aria2.

aria2 is a lightweight multi-protocol & multi-source command-line download utility. It supports HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, BitTorrent and Metalink. aria2 can be manipulated via built-in JSON-RPC and XML-RPC interfaces.<sup>[aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

Also you may want to look at [Curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl), and [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)